# How to view the source code of a NMF algorithm in R?

Tags: r, nmf

I am pretty new using R, I have to program a new NMF algorithm to be used as the parameter `method` when the function `nmf()` is called.

As a way to start I would like to view the source code of the built-in algorithms as brunet, KL, lee, but I am unable to find it. Can someone help me please?

Comment: From which package is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the source [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMF/index.html) and then inspect the code for the function you are interested in. Additionally, try typing the name of the function at the console. If it is written in R you may see the whole function printed out. E.g.

```
f <- function(x) {return(x^2)}
f

function(x) {return(x^2)}
```

If the function is written in C/C++ it will give you information that it is compiled and you can look for the function in the downloaded source code, e.g.

```
head
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("head")
<bytecode: 0x10a0d9158>
<environment: namespace:utils>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rstudio, in R script you can hold Ctrl and click on the name of the function it jumps to the function source.

Comment: I think it only works in source not the console... In Rstudio

Answer (score 0):

```
library(NMF)
showMethods("nmf")

Function: nmf (package NMF)
x="data.frame", rank="ANY", method="ANY"
x="formula", rank="ANY", method="ANY"
x="matrix", rank="data.frame", method="ANY"
x="matrix", rank="matrix", method="ANY"
x="matrix", rank="missing", method="ANY"
x="matrix", rank="NMF", method="ANY"
x="matrix", rank="NULL", method="ANY"
x="matrix", rank="numeric", method="character"
x="matrix", rank="numeric", method="function"
x="matrix", rank="numeric", method="list"
x="matrix", rank="numeric", method="missing"
x="matrix", rank="numeric", method="NMFStrategy"
x="matrix", rank="numeric", method="NULL"
```

Next select the method for which you want to see the source code as in

```
selectMethod("nmf", c("matrix", "matrix", "ANY"))
selectMethod("nmf", c("data.frame", "ANY", "ANY"))
```